# Keep duplicates on multiple columns in R

Tags: r

I have this dataset:

```
# A tibble: 15 x 4
# Groups:   bat [3]
   bat     log rocc     id
   <fct> <int> <fct> <int>
 1 A         1 occ       1
 2 A         2 nocc      1
 3 A         3 rent      1
 4 A         4 rent      1
 5 A         5 rent      1
 6 C         7 occ       3
 7 C         8 rent      4
 8 C         9 rent      5
 9 C        10 nocc      5
10 D        11 rent      6
11 D        12 rent      7
12 D        13 rent      8
13 D        14 nocc      9
14 D        15 rent     10
15 D        16 nocc     11
```

I would like to **filter only the bat's having the same id** so, only the lines of bat A in this reduced dataset. I tried a code with dplyr and duplicated, but R keeps also the two lines of bat C having the same id... Hope it's clear :)

Expected output:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Groups:   bat [1]
   bat     log rocc     id
   <fct> <int> <fct> <int>
 1 A         1 occ       1
 2 A         2 nocc      1
 3 A         3 rent      1
 4 A         4 rent      1
 5 A         5 rent      1
```

Any suitable solutions? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please share the output using `dput`

Comment: Hello Sonny, sorry, new here :)

Comment: Can you paste the expected output?

Comment: Whats your expected output?

Comment: I modified the question. More clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something very simple like this should work:

```
df %>%
  group_by(bat) %>%
  filter(length(unique(id)) == 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to remove duplicate on "bat" and "id" columns, lets say you have data frame DF, try this :

```
DF[!duplicated(DF[c(1,4)]),]
```